# How can I distinguish between multiple JSliders in an ActionListener?

Tags: java, actionlistener, jslider

I want to creat a GUI in which I display a dynamical number of lines containing each a JSlider and a JLabel that displays the value (see mockup).

[image: Multiple JSlider with related labels]

Now I have to update each label on a change of the related slider. And I want to use one common ActionListener. I thought there is something similar like a ActionCommand for JButton to identify which slider did change. But there isn't :-(

My only idea is to store a HashMap with key=slider reference and value=label reference. Is there a more elegant solution?

edit:
With more elegant I mean: without the need of storing references of the sliders and labels, so I don't have to update the HashTable when changing the number of lines.

Comment: Could you use getSource() on the event and check it against the sliders? Granted, that would only work if the sliders are class variables

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener() {

  JSlider slider1 = new JSlider();
  JSlider slider2 = new JSlider();

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == slider1) {
      //do logic for slider 1
    } else if (e.getSource() == slider2) {
      //do logic for slider 2
    }
    //etc...
  }
  //rest of class here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon, this would be my solution with the HashTable, where I store all references and I always have to update the table when I change the number of sliders. So I'm searching for a more elegant solution without the need of storing the references.